# Python string manipulation. Adding a character to the fifth place

Tags: python, string, list, hex

I think the best way to express my question is by showing an example:

I have a hex number, say `2f`. I want to take this hex number and put a '9' in the fifth place, followed by zero's. So in this case I want  `9002f`. From here I will do convert this back to decimal.

I was thinking the best way to do this is by using lists and having a list of `['9','0','0','0','0']` and a list of `['2','f']` and somehow overwriting to the 9000 list.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do the string manipulation at all?  It sounds like you want to do math with hex numbers:

```
h = '2f'
h_int = int(h, 16)
h_int += 0x90000
```

If you really need to get the string, you can then turn it back into a string:

```
"%x" % h_int
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want

```
def fillhex(h, n, pos):
    return n+h.zfill(pos-len(n))
```

.

```
fillhex('2f', '9', 5)
9002f

fillhex('4A', '9', 5)
9004A

fillhex('F', '9', 5)
9000F
```

Though there are easier ways to convert between number bases as @NedBatchelder shows in his answer.

Comment: If the numbers are already in string form, it may be slower to convert to int, do the math and make a string again.

Answer (score 0):

Funny requirements, but that works for a variable position:

```
>>> def place_n(a, b, pos):
    return '{0}{1:0>{2}}'.format(a, b, pos - len(a))

>>> place_n('9', '2f', 5)
'9002f'
```